# How to get properties from multiple vertexes in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

How to get properties from multiple vertexes in a gremlin.[image]

From the above graph, I need to collect 'name' from `user` and email_id from `email` vertex and phone number from `phone_number` vertex. Is it possible to collect all properties in one query?

I tried the below query but it returns `email` and `phone_number` as a separate item

```
g.V().hasLabel('user').as('u').outE('owns')
.inV().hasLabel('email', 'phone_number').as('e', 'p').select('u', 'e', 'p').by(elementMap('name')).by(elementMap()).by(elementMap())
```

output

```
{'u': {<T.id: 1>: '124848d5-f387-48eb-bbb7-ad193ef6070a', <T.label: 4>: 'user', 'name': 'Thirumal'}, 'e': {<T.id: 1>: '922f4ac1-9c6d-40fa-bac2-682e0f01673a', <T.label: 4>: 'phone_number', 'phone_number': '+918973697871'}, 'p': {<T.id: 1>: '922f4ac1-9c6d-40fa-bac2-682e0f01673a', <T.label: 4>: 'phone_number', 'phone_number': '+918973697871'}}

{'u': {<T.id: 1>: '124848d5-f387-48eb-bbb7-ad193ef6070a', <T.label: 4>: 'user', 'name': 'Thirumal'}, 'e': {<T.id: 1>: '2c3f90a4-d8bd-4cf5-9ff0-d4e3a6cf1190', <T.label: 4>: 'email', 'email': 'thirumal@enkindletech.com'}, 'p': {<T.id: 1>: '2c3f90a4-d8bd-4cf5-9ff0-d4e3a6cf1190', <T.label: 4>: 'email', 'email': 'thirumal@enkindletech.com'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of issues is commonly handled by `project()`:

```
g.V().hasLabel('user').
  project('name','email','phone').
    by('name').
    by(out('owns').hasLabel('email').values("email")).
    by(out('owns').hasLabel('phone_number').values('phone_number'))
```